# How can I monitor ASP.NET MVC server load and performance without access to IIS log files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, monitoring, appharbor

I need to monitor the load and performance on my ASP.NET MVC web service application.  The application is hosted on AppHarbor and behind a load balancer.  Currently just running 2 web workers.  Some of the data we're trying to collect:

- average/peak load in hits per second
- min/max/average request processing time

AppHarbor has been promising access to IIS logs for some time, but as far as I can tell it has yet to materialize.  I'm thinking of just rolling my own ASP.NET filter or something to log each request to a database, but I'm a little worried of impacting performance negatively by introducing a database write on each request.

This is not a very high traffic application at the moment.  Hard to tell with no logs, but my guess is on the order of a few hundred thousand requests per month.

Are there any off the shelf packages I should consider?  Is it worth considering some kind of cloud based logging/analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably take a look at the [New Relic add-on](https://appharbor.com/addons/newrelic). AppHarbor has a bunch of other [monitoring add-ons](https://appharbor.com/addons) that might work for your use. [Hosted Graphite](http://blog.appharbor.com/2013/02/22/hosted-graphite-now-in-add-on-catalog) is another one.